# wptools Wikipedia API bug?

Tags: json, api, web-scraping, typeerror, wikipedia

I am not sure why I am getting this error when I run the following method:

```
import wptools
wptools.page('E.T._the_Extra-Terrestrial').get()

*TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'*
```

I have confirmed that this command works on other computers so I'm not sure if there is a bug within the library or if I'm just missing something.

I am running windows 10. 
'3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.1.1 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  5 2016, 11:41:13) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I confirmed there was a bug.  Developer has updated it.  See github issue for reference.

https://github.com/siznax/wptools/issues/95